# OnTouchListener handles only ACTION_DOWN

Tags: android, touch, ontouchlistener

It handles only ACTION_DOWN (in new project also). No event ACTION_UP, ACTION_MOVE:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.d("DOWN", "S");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.d("MOVE", "S");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                Log.d("UP", "S");
                break;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Displays only ACTION_DOWN:               `Log.d(Integer.toString(event.getAction()), "");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That because:

```
return false;
```

It mean you don't receive any events after `ACTION_DOWN`.

Change to:

```
return true;
```